# Can't start Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

When I put “hg —version” in my mac terminal, it shows below Error…

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 41, in <module>
    mercurial.util.setbinary(fp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 106, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 78, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 70, in <module>
    statfiles = getattr(osutil, 'statfiles', platform.statfiles)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 106, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 78, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so, 2): Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/osutil.so
```

How I fix this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

PS : Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got Answer…!

*Step1:* Go to  “**/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages**” folder.

```
>$ cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

*Step2:* Remove below files in "**site-packages**" folder.

```
>$ rm -rf hgext                           
>$ rm -rf mercurial               
>$ rm -rf mercurial-3.7.3-py2.7.egg-info
```

*Step 3:* Now **install mercurial**